# Grails i18n: Organisation of local files?

Tags: grails

I read the [official document of the i18n plugin](http://grails.org/doc/2.4.3/guide/i18n.html), but it seems that it doesn't mention if it's possible to organises the separated `message` files for each controller/view.

(but as a feature of Rails, you can check it [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#organization-of-locale-files))

So is it possible to do that like the Rails way? separate the i18n files for each controller/view? or i can only write all strings into `messages.properties`.

Answer (score 1):

You can have as many files containing messages as you want and use your preferred organizational structure.

Name the file however you want (e.g. `loginController.properties` and append language name postfixes to translated versions the same way Grails does for the default file (e.g. `loginController_de.properties`).

It doesn't seem like you can use subfolders, though - all files must be in `/grails-app/i18n`.